Disable automatic closing of quotes in Visual Studio
I'm trying to disable automatic closing of quotes (and only quotes) in Visual Studio Professional 2022.
This can't be done in settings because this flag is coupled with automatic closing of brackets.
So I've removed quotes from relevant definitions in language settings file ("csharp-language-configuration.json"), so it looks like this:
  "autoClosingPairs": [
    { "open": "{", "close": "}" },
    { "open": "[", "close": "]" },
    { "open": "(", "close": ")" },
    {
      "open": "/*",
      "close": "*/",
      "notIn": [ "string" ]
    }
  ],

And this works, but only for newly created files. Can this be done for existing files?

From my point of view this is due to the end of line character, my existing file sometimes work but sometimes doesn't for disabling automatic quote completion, and I don't think there is an official way to change this currently,maybe you could explore the market for extensions to tweak your VS according to your requirements.
